# When memory is leaking can it be plugged if the program is ran again the leak is accounted for?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Say I have I create something like this `int pointer` and `pointer = new int[10];`.  Now if forget to use the `delete[]` when i'm done with my array, we will have memory leaking.  But what happens if shut down my IDE and starting it back up again with the same code but this time i add a `delete[] pointer` will the leak caused by the first time the program ran be plugged or is it still there... forever?

Comment: Memory is lost until that **process (not your IDE) terminates**. _Usually_ Operating System frees allocated memory (even when you forget to do it by yourself, in most but not all OSes).

Comment: `delete[] pointer` won't work anyway because `pointer` will be either uninitialised or null.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Could you point out an OS which doesn't free all of the resources which belong to a process which terminates?

Comment: @JamesKanze tiny OSes for embedded devices (but C is used more than C++ there). One highly used one? MSDOS. Still in use in tons of appliance, old small devices and - sadly - big legacy systems. Probably nothing OP has to care about but better to be aware it's just a reasonable assumption and not a rule.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti MSDOS frees all of the memory, unless you've declared it to be TSR.  For embedded devices, I would expect that the system is not hosted, in which case, it's not even certain that it supports dynamic allocation, and there's not really the equivalent of what you would call a process under the usual OSs.

Comment: @JamesKanze as far as I remember (hard to try now...) no, it'll keep **process** in memory if you terminate asking to be TSR (`int` _something_? `int 21h` dos function? I don't remember) but it'll do nothing about dynamic memory you allocated. OS for an embedded device can be pretty little but it's still an OS and not necessarily single process (especially true for 7/24 devices).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It could depend on the compiler, but the compilers I used would `malloc` from the process space, not from some unrelated memory.  I know that in one case, I intentionally didn't `free`, because I had thousands of small blocks, and freeing them would cause the process to stall when terminating.

Comment: @JamesKanze ahhh `jmp` to _good_ old times! Just check with TC++ 2.0 on MSDOS 6.22 and _plain_ `malloc()` effectively uses DOS function `48h` then memory will be freed when process exits with `4Ch`. Was it DPMI with DOS4/G on Watcom? I can't remember anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leak is local to your program as long as it keeps running. It may be that you ran the program within the IDE or separately using command line, but when the program you are running exists the operating system reclaims the memory.

As far as I know restarting your IDE should not have any effect with the memory of the program your are running.

Comment: Okay, if I"m understanding this its okay if the program I was running crashed before it reached `delete[]` part while coding, I won't have permanent memory leak on my computer caused by the IDE compiling the program.  I am asking because there's a language barrier with my professor and I got the impression that if the program you're developing crashes at any time before it reaches delete[] part then it'll cause memory leaks on your computer.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. You won't have a permanent memory leak on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Closing your IDE will do nothing.

When your application exits the OS will 'clear' the memory used by your application. (mark it all as unused).

Your IDE handles the launching of your application, and (probably) runs the debugger for it too, but the application is still seperate from your IDE.  When your application runs, none of the memory it uses belongs to the IDE. When it terminates, because the IDE is disconnected, all the memory the app uses is free'd and the fact that the IDE remains open does not hinder this or cause memory to be leaked from the IDE.

Comment: No, it's really the OS that clears it. No existing C++ runtime bothers.

Comment: Really? ok, fixed. I suppose it makes sense.

Comment: "actually it's the the c++ runtime" - No, it's (almost certainly) the OS. Otherwise you'd leak memory permanently if the process were aborted.